# Por qué no puedo ingresar una Imagen en un Jtable java

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

Este es el código que quiero insertar:

```
jTableSesiones.setValueAt(new 
ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\invitado\\Desktop\\FIRMA9.png")), 
0, 0);
```

y me lanza el siguiente error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si intentas agregar la imagen al mismo package del proyecto, y ahi ingresarlo como

ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("nombre_proyecto\package\FIRMA9.png")), 
0, 0);

Comment: Para que sea mejor recibida tu respuesta amplia la explicación